# Quasar with Asp.NET Core WebApi IIS publish 403 error

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, webapi, quasar

In development stage, the quasar project can be hosted and run under the IIS virtal application. When published, copied files from dist folder to iis root directory, the index page display normally, but  there is an error 403 when using webapi url to make a httppost request. I have used IIS UrlRewrite component. It seemed that the issue related with the webapi request conflict with the urlrewrite.

1. the web.config file contains url rewrite rules

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
       <rewrite>
        <rules>
         <rule name="Handle History Mode and custom 404/500" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
         </rule>
        </rules>
       </rewrite>
     <httpErrors> 
       <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" /> 
       <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
       <error statusCode="404" path="/survey/notfound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" /> 
       <error statusCode="500" path="/survey/error" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      </httpErrors>
     </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

2. the startup.cs file contains controller route pattern

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
    
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthorization()
            .UseCors("AllowAll");
    
    
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "api/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
        app.UseSpa(spa =>
       {
           spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
    
           if (env.IsDevelopment())
           {
               spa.UseVueCli(npmScript: "serve", forceKill: true);
           }
       });
    }
```

3. IIS 403 error
   When there is webapi request, the error happens...

http://localhost/webdemo2/api/wf/QueryProcessRoles

There is an article is useful to deploy quasar project to IIS, but the error 403 still exist. Could anyone find a solution here? Thanks

https://forum.quasar-framework.org/topic/3004/deploy-quasar-application-in-iis

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for 403 error, you can try below methods to slove the question:

1.The 403 error page will appear if the right permissions are not given to the folder. you need to assign IIS_IUSRS security permissions to your assigned web folder.

Right click on the folder you assigned for web access in IIS, Choose "Properties" and then go to "Security" tab. In the top box, "Group or user names", open "Edit…", You will most likely cannot fine IIS_IUSRS in the list; open, "Add..", In the box at the very bottom, "Enter the object names to select (examples):" enter IIS_IUSRS, Click OK and make sure in the Permissions window, you have allowed, Read & execute, List folder contents and Read

2.Please check if you set the [default document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/configure-default-document-iis).